# Place BitmapFont and Texture at the same Y position in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I draw two strings using a BitmapFont (font) and two textures (starIcon, clockIcon) in the same Y position (top - iconSize). Where iconSize is height of the icon. But the result is totally off. See the image below. What am I doing wrong here.

[image]

```
        batch.draw(starIcon, hmargin, top - iconSize, iconSize, iconSize);
        batch.draw(clockIcon, width*0.65f, top - iconSize,  iconSize, iconSize);
        font.draw(batch, scoreString, hmargin + iconSize + tmargin, top - iconSize);
        font.draw(batch, timeString, width*0.65f + tmargin + iconSize, top - iconSize);
```

Comment: you can try startIcon.getTop or starIcon.getY

Answer (score 0):

```
font.draw(batch, scoreString, hmargin + iconSize + tmargin, top - iconSize+font.getCapHeight());
```

Use `capHeight` of `BitmapFont`, which is the distance from the top of most uppercase characters to the baseline, cap height can be used to get the location of the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

When using Textures, the origin is the lower-left corner. But! When using a bitmap font, the origin is the **upper-left corner**.
Thus, if you want the text to match the image on the bottom line, do so:

```
font.draw(batch, scoreString, hmargin + iconSize + tmargin, top - iconSize + textHeight));
```

if you want the text in the middle of the image, do so:

```
font.draw(batch, scoreString, hmargin + iconSize + tmargin, top - iconSize/2 + textHeight/2);
```

To find out the height of the bimmapfont-text, I use GlyphLayuot.